# How do I redirect http request to https in Redstone?

Tags: dart, redstone.dart

In expressjs, I can do

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if((!req.secure) && (req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') !== 'https')) {
        res.redirect('https://' + req.get('Host') + req.url);
        console.log('redirected http request to https');
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

to redirect http request to https.

How do I do it in readstone?

I tried following, it does not work.

```
@app.Route('/')
adlMain() {
  if (app.request.requestedUri.scheme != 'https') {
    var httpsUrl = app.request.requestedUri.replace(scheme:   'https').toString();
    app.redirect(httpsUrl);
  }
  return new File('build/web/index.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result of `app.redirect`:

```
return app.redirect(httpsUrl);
```

This is different than in Express, as Express uses a response object to write headers and content to while Redstone uses a return value.